# Is it possible to have a sprite fade out from left to right?

Tags: cocoa, cocos2d-iphone, action, fadeout

I have a full screen animation and I am wondering if it is possible to run a fadeOut from left to right action on the sprite?

Comment: not understanding your question Stephen ... do you mean like a "wave of transparency" that sweeps over it and makes it vanish from left to right ?  I wrote a shader for something similar for a 'health urn', i can animate the depletion or fill-up in a similar fashion (top to bottom). Shader was the easiest for me but it works fine. Maybe some GL gurus can suggest other means.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg the way you explained it with a wave of transparency is exactly how I need it to work. Could you explain how I could achieve this?